# How to create an entity command such that generating a SQL query that includes only the specified bindings while avoiding null values?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, cqrs

I using the CQRS pattern for CRUD Operations, so in this scenario I want to insert operation and I have "CommunicationEntity" which contains 6 properties.

```
public class InsertCommunicationCommand
{
    // Include only the properties you want to insert
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }

    // Add any validation logic if needed
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        // Implement your validation logic here
        return true;
    }
}




public class InsertCommunicationCommandHandler
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

    public InsertCommunicationCommandHandler(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Handle(InsertCommunicationCommand command)
    {
        if (!command.IsValid())
        {
            // Handle validation errors
            return;
        }

        // Create a new CommunicationEntity with only the properties you want to insert
        var entity = new CommunicationEntity
        {
            Property1 = command.Property1,
            Property2 = command.Property2
        };

        // Attach the entity to the context and mark it as added
        
        _dbContext.CommunicationEntities.Add(entity);

        // Save changes to the database
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I want to insert a record with two properties but the entity generates SQL query for the insert operation mentioning all the properties instead of two properties -

```
INSERT INTO tblCommunication (
    [Property1], 
    [Property2],
    [Property3],
    [Property4],
    [Property5],
    [Property6],
)
VALUES (
    i.[Property1], 
    i.[Property2],
    i.[Property3],
    i.[Property4],
    i.[Property5]
)
```

But I want to write entity framework command in a such way that behind the scene it would generate SQL query for only those values which are modified as following -

```
INSERT INTO tblCommunication(
    [Property1], 
    [Property2]
)
VALUES (
    i.[Property1], 
    i.[Property2]
)
```

So using entity framework is there any way whereby only the properties which I set the value for goes for inserting in the .net core?

Comment: Any specific reason to care only about the two properties? EF usually 'knows what its doing' to a dregree that I'd recommend not to worry about whats happening behind the scenes - which is usually the reason for using EF to begin with..

Comment: @SanchoPanza I have a dynamic JSON such that if JSON contains several properties then those properties should be inserted on the table I have tackled that but while doing let's say two properties but insert query generated behind it mentions all the properties, currently I have 20+ properties in entity so thats why.

Comment: Is that for performance issues? If there are a lot of properties that are not going to be set, I think you have a spars entity issue. You can't make EF generate an insertion query for exactly those properties. You should consider T-SQL commands.

Comment: You could try to implementing the DTO approach where you explicitly set the values of the properties you want to include in the database.`public class CommunicationDto
   {
       public string Property1 { get; set; }
       public string Property2 { get; set; }
       // Add other properties as needed
   }`
Instead of directly creating a `CommunicationEntity`, create a `CommunicationDto` instance and map it to your `CommunicationEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your tblCommunication is setup you could pass it an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) with only the properties set that you want to be in your query.

```
_dbContext.CommunicationEntities.Add(new {command.property1, command.property2});
```

If the properties need to be dynamic you should look into [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can only add the properties you need and leave the others out.

Be aware that the db fields you are leaving out they need to be nullable or have a default value.

Comment: tried but _dbContext.CommunicationEntities.Add() not allowing dynamic object